# Python: How to find which values in a column have NaN values in another specific column (dataframes)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, nan

Suppose we have `df1` that looks like this:

```
x1 = [{'partner': "Afghanistan", 'commodity': NaN}, 
      {'partner': "Zambia",      'commodity': 2}, 
      {'partner': "Germany",     'commodity': 2},
      {'partner': "Afghanistan", 'commodity': NaN},
      {'partner': "Canada",      'commodity': NaN},
      {'partner': "Italy",       'commodity': 3},
      {'partner': "Canada",      'commodity': NaN},
      {'partner': "USA",         'commodity': NaN}]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(x1)
```

What I want to do is see the list of values in `partner` that have the `NaN` value in `commodity`, but I don't want to have the same `partner` listed twice.

So my preferred result would look like this:

```
commodity_nan_partners=
Afghanistan
Canada
USA
```

and not:

```
Afghanistan
Afghanistan
Canada
Canada
USA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) + [`isnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html) + [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html)

You can filter your series and then drop duplicates:

```
res = df1.loc[df1['commodity'].isnull(), 'partner'].drop_duplicates()

print(res)

0    Afghanistan
4         Canada
7            USA
Name: partner, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3):

You can look for `NaN` values using `isnull`, then get unique values with `unique` or `set`:

```
>>> pd.Series(df1.loc[df1.commodity.isnull(),'partner'].unique())
0    Afghanistan
1         Canada
2            USA
dtype: object

# or
>>> pd.Series(list(set(df1.loc[df1.commodity.isnull(),'partner'])))
0         Canada
1    Afghanistan
2            USA
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1**
Filter out to retain valid strings only:

```
v = df1.loc[df1.commodity.isna(), 'partner']
```

Or,

```
v = df1.partner[df1.commodity.isna()]
```

```
print(v)
0    Afghanistan
3    Afghanistan
4         Canada
6         Canada
7            USA
Name: partner, dtype: object
```

**Step 2**
Drop duplicates.

If you want a collection,

```
ingredients.unique()
array(['Afghanistan', 'Canada', 'USA'], dtype=object)
```

Or,

```
set(ingredients)
{'Afghanistan', 'Canada', 'USA'}
```

If you want a Series,

```
ser = ingredients.drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)

0    Afghanistan
1         Canada
2            USA
Name: partner, dtype: object
```

If you want a DataFrame,

```
df = ser.to_frame()
```

Answer (score 2):

May check with `dropna` , just provide a different Idea here .

```
set(df1.partner.tolist())-set(df1.dropna().partner.tolist())
Out[94]: {'Afghanistan', 'Canada', 'USA'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another alternatives:

```
>>> df1[df1.isnull().any(axis=1)]['partner'].drop_duplicates()
0    Afghanistan
4         Canada
7            USA
Name: partner, dtype: object
```

Using `loc` + `np.isnan`

```
>>> df1.loc[np.isnan(df1.commodity), 'partner'].drop_duplicates()
0    Afghanistan
4         Canada
7            USA
Name: partner, dtype: object
```